# How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{x}{1+\cos^2x}dx$

Tags: integration

How to evaluate:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{x}{1+\cos^2x}dx$$

(maybe the question is wrong)

Comment: If you think it's hard it must mean you done some attempts, what were they? If you tell us, maybe someone can point out where you went wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Hint...try substituting $u=\pi-x$.....

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=\pi-x$.

$$\int_0^\pi \frac{x}{1+\cos^2x}dx=-\int_\pi^0 \frac{\pi-u}{1+\cos^2(\pi-u)}du=\pi\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{1+\cos^2u}dx-\int_0^\pi \frac{u}{1+\cos^2u}du$$

So,

$$\int_0^\pi \frac{x}{1+\cos^2x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{1+\cos^2x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\pi \frac{\sec^2x}{2+\tan^2x}dx$$

Then let $\tan x=\sqrt{2}\tan \theta$.

Comment: @Thorne Which method?

Comment: Thx ,but When I use the following method, I get two different results,why?
$$
\int_0^\pi \frac{x}{1+\cos^2x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{1+\cos^2x}dx=\pi\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\sec^2x}{2+\tan^2x}dx=\frac{\pi^2}{2\sqrt2}
$$

Comment: Your answer is correct, which is also equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\pi \frac{\sec^2x}{2+\tan^2x}dx$.

Comment: mathematica solve result  3.48943
$$\int_0^\pi \frac{x}{1+\cos^2x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{1+\cos^2x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\pi \frac{\sec^2x}{2+\tan^2x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt2}arctan(\frac{tan(x)}{\sqrt2})\big|_{0}^{\pi}=0$$

Comment: As $\tan x$ is undefined at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$. The integral in my solution is improper and cannot be $\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left.\textrm{arctan}\left(\frac{\tan x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right|_0^\pi$. We have to break it down into two integrals. Your work in the first comment is the correct way.

Comment: thank you very much ,I fully understand